# Basic interface publishing with nuget

Tags: .net, nuget

I maintain a Library assembly, `MyLibrary.dll`, which is distributed as part of a larger application, along with an interface assembly `MyLibrary.API.dll`

I would like to publish a nuget package to contain the interface specification to my Library, and the XML documentation, so other applications can talk to my Library.

I think I need my nuget file to contain `MyLibrary.API.dll` and `MyLibrary.API.xml`, to be used as reference assembly, but neither copied to the consuming project's output directory.

What is the magic setting I need in the Visual Studio project that outputs MyLibrary.Integration-1.0.0.nupkg such what whatever projects reference it will be able to reference the API, but will not distribute the MyLibrary.API.dll file by mistake? I suppose my package project needs to set a flag that eventually leads to a default constraint of "IncludeAssets=compile" in the PackageReference of any consuming project. If the consuming projects are themselves nuget packages, they should not have a dependency on MyLibrary.API.dll

Am I even going the right way about publishing my interface documentation?

Comment: Did you solve this one?

Comment: I have no solution yet; the project is on the back-burner, so I haven't been actively investigating a solution.